# Adding 1 every second to a certain variable

Tags: javascript, addition, intervals

I just want to add `1` to a certain variable every second while the program is running.

So basically it kind of performs something like x++ every second.

I see many setIntervals but they use var which is not working.

I'm new to Java so please bear with me.

Comment: `var` and `setInterval` are Javascript, not Java. you want to use the `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` method

Comment: Please clarify if you are programming in Java, the Object Oriented Language which runs on a JVM, or JavaScript, an implementation of ECMAScript which runs in your browser. Java has nothing to do with JavaScript despite the unfortunate naming collision.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sleep command in your loop before running the x++.  The sleep command is in milliseconds so you'll have something like the following pseudo code:

```
LoopWithConditional{

sleep(60000);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a thread-safe way to increment the int. The best way is to use `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

Then, you need some timed task to increment that `AtomicInteger` every second. For that, you can use [`Timer.schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)).

```
private final AtomicInteger myInt = new AtomicInteger(0); // start at 0

public void startIncrementing() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myInt.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
    Timer timer = new Timer(true); // you probably want a daemon thread here
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000); // start right away, repeat every 1000 ms
}
```

If you want to be able to stop the increments, you'll need to save the `timer` into an instance variable so that you can call `timer.cancel()` on it when you want to stop incrementing.

I'd encourage you to read up on the javadocs of the various classes/methods here, because there's lots of juicy stuff (such as what a daemon thread is, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the JavaScript date object as follows:

```
//At the beginning of your app
var d = new Date();
var startSeconds = d.getTime()/1000

//Whenever you need the incremental variable by one every second

x = (d.getTime()/1000) - startSeconds
```